# wglCreatePbufferARB with compatible device context

Tags: windows, opengl, pixel, gdi

Is it possible to create `pBuffer` using `wglCreatePbufferARB` for a compatible device context ?

```
HDC fHDC = ::GetDC((HWND)_window);
HDC _fHDC = ::CreateCompatibleDC(fHDC);
HBITMAP memBM = ::CreateCompatibleBitmap ( fHDC, bounds.xMax - bounds.xMin, bounds.yMax - bounds.yMin );
::SelectObject ( _fHDC, memBM );

later on, i'm creating pBuffer using calls -    
wglChoosePixelFormatARB(_fHDC, iAttribList, fAttribList, 1,
                                &pixelFormat, &numFormats)

hBuffer=wglCreatePbufferARB(_fHDC, pixelFormat, width, height, flags);
```

My call to `wglChoosePixelFormatARB` is failing

Comment: cannot you use Framebuffer Object? it would be unrelated to WGL functionality that way...

Comment: @fen: I hope you meant Pixelbuffer Object? FBOs aren't even buffer objects, they just manage state for read/draw buffers.

Comment: Logically, I do not think this makes any sense. A compatible DC is one that has the same format as its parent, you really have no choice in pixel format... nothing is violated according to the WGL spec., however. Have you tried using fHDC as the base DC for this call? In any event, Pixel Buffer Objects are really the way to go, they are window system agnostic and widely supported on all modern OpenGL implementations.